# Geodesics Examples

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Can someone provide me exemples of connected Riemannian manifolds containing two points through each there are : (i) infinitely many geodesics (up to reparametrization)  and   (ii) no geodesics.

Thank you

Comment: For infinitely-many, if I understood you well, $S^2$ could work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so for (i) we can consider $S^{2}$ and for (ii) we can consider $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus\lbrace 0\rbrace$ (with Euclidian metric).

Thanks anyway and have a nice weekend :)